# Writing Name/Value Pair to JSON Object

Tags: c, json

This question is about two small functions used in a project about server-related communication and encryption. So far I have programmed only in C, but owing to the nature of the project, I am instructed to use JavaScript by means of the Parson Header File (parson.h).

> Could someone please help me rid my code of the warnings in the two
>   functions below? An elaboration will follow the code.

Usually I would be able to fix these types of things, but now I'm not really sure where the problem is...

```
//Write a function to write a name/value pair to a given JSON value containing an object. The function prototype must be as follows:
void setNameValuePair(JSON_Value *rootValue, const char *name, const char *value) {
//This is of course the body of the function I wrote
json_object_set_string(rootValue, name, value);
}

//Write a function that reads the value associated with a specific name in a given JSON value containing an object. The function prototype must be as follows:
const char* getValueFromName(const JSON_Value *rootValue, const char *name) { 
//And here is my function body again
const char *value;  
value = json_object_dotget_string(rootValue, name);     
return value; 
}
```

In both cases I don't technically get an error, but two similar warnings (I believe there's a difference) stating the following:

`passing argument 1 of 'json_object_set_string' from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]`,

and

`passing argument 1 of 'json_object_dotget_string' from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]`.

It states that the above is "enabled by default", but when testing the functions, my program crashes.

I have received some comments advising me to look up the functions I'm calling from parson.h and take note of the parameters they require - I found this, but I would appreciate help making sense of it:

```
/* dotget functions enable addressing values with dot notation in nested objects,
 just like in structs or c++/java/c# objects (e.g. objectA.objectB.value).
 Because valid names in JSON can contain dots, some values may be inaccessible
 this way. */
JSON_Value  * json_object_dotget_value  (const JSON_Object *object, const char *name);
const char  * json_object_dotget_string (const JSON_Object *object, const char *name);
JSON_Object * json_object_dotget_object (const JSON_Object *object, const char *name);
JSON_Array  * json_object_dotget_array  (const JSON_Object *object, const char *name);
double        json_object_dotget_number (const JSON_Object *object, const char *name); /* returns 0 on fail */
int           json_object_dotget_boolean(const JSON_Object *object, const char *name); /* returns -1 on fail */

/* Creates new name-value pair or frees and replaces old value with a new one.
 * json_object_set_value does not copy passed value so it shouldn't be freed afterwards. */
JSON_Status json_object_set_value(JSON_Object *object, const char *name, JSON_Value *value);
JSON_Status json_object_set_string(JSON_Object *object, const char *name, const char *string);
JSON_Status json_object_set_number(JSON_Object *object, const char *name, double number);
JSON_Status json_object_set_boolean(JSON_Object *object, const char *name, int boolean);
JSON_Status json_object_set_null(JSON_Object *object, const char *name);
```

I don't think I can expand, explain or include any more information. What you see now is all I have...

I suspect the solution to be very simple - the patch and perhaps a quick explanation would be appreciated!

Comment: We don't know what do the functions `json_object_...`! You seem to be trying to set a value on a const buffer! Furthermore are you sure that the resources are allocated for the buffer you are trying to modify ?

Comment: You are calling `json_object_*` incorrectly.  That is the most we can say with this amount of information.

Post the literal error text you receive.  Also read the function declarations in `parsons.h`.  It will describe what the functions expect to have as the first argument in there.

Comment: Find the json functions in Parson.h and see what they expect for parameters.  Post the exact error message, sometime is has all you need in it.

Comment: OK - thanks guys. I've taken a look at what you said and edited my question. Please see if this gives you a better understanding of what I should  be trying to do...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should pay attention to function declarations and comments in the file `parson.h`. If something is not clear you can also look at the file `parson.c` with implementation.

Your functions receive pointer to `JSON_Value`, but you try to pass this pointer to functions that accept pointer to `JSON_Object`. Those types are different. It is not enough just to cast one to another.

If you for sure know that provided `JSON_Value` contains an object it can be obtained using `json_value_get_object(root_value);`. However if `JSON_Value` is not an object (for example array or string) this function returns `NULL`. So if such case is possible proper handling is needed.

Required functions:

```
void setNameValuePair(JSON_Value *rootValue, const char *name, const char *value)
{
    /* NULL is returned if rootValue is not an object */
    JSON_Object *root_object = json_value_get_object(root_value);
    json_object_set_string(root_object, name, value);
}

const char* getValueFromName(const JSON_Value *rootValue, const char *name) 
{
    /* NULL is returned if rootValue is not an object */
    JSON_Object *root_object = json_value_get_object(root_value);

    /* NULL is returned if object field is not a string*/
    return json_object_dotget_string(root_object, name);
}
```

You should be also careful with memory allocations and memory leaks. For example, the function `json_object_dotget_string` returns not a copy of string, but it returns pointer to the same string that was used for creation of that JSON. So if the initial string is freed, the string returned by `getValueFromName` is also freed.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Not only does this have my functions passing the tests, but I also have a better understanding of what it is I'm doing. Appreciate the help!